# Live Chat Time-out

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, livechattranscript

How to configure a chat timeout message for the customer if he/she didnot reply in a given timeframe.Also how to set that timeframe on the customer end?

Answer (score 0):

Chat timeout message is not configurable. You need to make changes to the VF component - liveAgent:clientChatAlertMessage.
See the example- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_visualforce_components_code_sample.htm

Comment: Hi Manish,

Yes I have enabled that but thats only the timeframe.What about a customized timeout message?Is that configurable?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure the message by editing the Embedded Service Deployment Settings
Section : Additional branding > labels